# Extension methods with interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

Assume we have this model :

```
public abstract class AbstractTableReferentielEntity {}
public class EstimationTauxReussite : AbstractTableReferentielEntity { }
```

I created a extension method for all classes that inherit from AbstractTableReferentielEntity.

```
public static EntityItemViewModel ToEntityItem<T>(this T entity)
    where T : AbstractTableReferentielEntity {}
```

But for one specific type of AbstractTableReferentielEntity (like EstimationTauxReussite), I would like to perform a specific action, so I created a second extension method.

```
 public static EntityItemViewModel ToEntityItem(this EstimationTauxReussite entity) {}
```

**All extensions methods are declared in the same namespace.**

After that, I retrieve some data from a DB with Entity Framework :

```
protected List<EntityItemViewModel> GetAllActifEntityItem<T>()
    where T : AbstractTableReferentielEntity
{
    return Context
        .Set<T>()
        .Where(item => item.IsActif)
        .Select(item => item.ToEntityItem())
        .ToList();
}
```

It compiles.

When T at runtime is a EstimationTauxReussite type, it goes into the wrong method `ToEntityItem` when I call `Select(item => item.ToEntityItem())`. It doesn't go into the most specific extension method. Any ideas ?

Comment: An extension method should never take priority, so this is odd behaviour.

Comment: Did you do any changes to the database? If so please update the entity framework. I have also face same kind of problem when I do changes on database.

Comment: @Nivs, it has nothing to do with Entity Framework or the database, it's just because extension methods are just static methods and so they don't participate in polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because extension methods are just syntactic sugar for static methods. The method to call is resolved at compile time based on the compile-time type of the argument, there is no virtual dispatch involved.

In your `GetAllActifEntityItem` method, the compiler only knows that `T` is a `AbstractTableReferentielEntity`, so it resolves the `ToEntityItem` method based on that. The fact that it will actually be called with `EstimationTauxReussite` for `T` is irrelevant.

A possible workaround would be to make `ToEntityItem` a virtual member method of `AbstractTableReferentielEntity`, and override it in `EstimationTauxReussite`. This way, virtual dispatch will occur as expected and the correct method will be called.

Comment: When you know that it's obvious. Your workaround worked for me, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that extension methods are "syntactic sugar", ie they are a compiler trick. Your line:

```
.Select(item => item.ToEntityItem())
```

is effectively converted by the compiler to:

```
.Select(item => StaticClassWithExtensionMethod.ToEntityItem(item))
```

and then turned into IL. This means that the type of `item` has to be determined at compile-time, not runtime. So the `AbstractTableReferentielEntity` version of the extension method is used as that's the one tht matches the type at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

**If i have access to sources of `AbstractTableReferentielEntity` and `EstimationTauxReussite`  classes** i would remake them in following way

1. Add virtual ToEntityItem method to AbstractTableReferentielEntity class
2. Override it in EstimationTauxReussite class
3. Delete both extension methods

Now `Select(item => item.ToEntityItem())` should pick method depends on input object